# Unity: Filter to give slight color variations to whole scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d, shader

In Unity, is there a way to give slight color variations to a scene (a strain of purple here, some yellow blur there) without adjusting every single texture? And for that to work in VR stereo images too (and ideally in semi-consistent way as one moves around, and perhaps also without having to use computing-heavy colored lights)? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to achieve this if your color effect is fixed would be to add a canvas that renders a half transparent image to the whole screen. But I suppose that you might prefer some dynamic effect.

To achieve this, look at Unity's [post processing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessingOverview.html) stack. It allows you to add many post process effects, such as chromatic aberation and color grading, that might allow you to do what you want

Comment: Thanks! I guess the color "randomizer" effect I'm trying to go for would be semi-attached to particular shape parts, introducing colors that weren't there before. That is probably the difficult part.